# Adding a banner below header in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, header

I'm trying to add a banner/content below the header in selected page.
I tried the code below but isnt working:

```
add_action ('__after_header' , 'add_content_after_header', 20);

function add_content_after_header() {
    //checks if we are displaying the home page
    if ( !tc__f( '__is_home' ) )
        return;
    ?>
        <div id="my-content-header">
        <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

Then I tried another code, which is working but showing the content on top of header:

```
add_action ('wp_head' , 'add_content_after_header', 20);

function add_content_after_header() {
    //checks if we are displaying the home page
  global $post;
  if ($post->post_type == 'page' && $post->ID == '7')
        return;
    ?>
        <div id="my-content-header">
        <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

Basically '__after_header' action isn't working for me but 'wp_head' action shows the content on top of header.
Any Idea how to solve this and have the content below the header?

Comment: Why not add it to the header template?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid direct theme edits so I can still use the updates.

Comment: Just use a child theme. It’s always better to keep content and logic separate where possible and the template files are where content belongs.

Comment: @FluffyKitten How?